# How can I stop Gmail from serving me auto translations based on my IP address?

Tags: gmail, localization

When I go to Gmail website (FireFox, if this info is needed) with a different IP (IP from Germany), they automatically translate the page to German.

How do I stop this behavior (in other words I want English no matter what)

Like even before I login to my account, the login page is already in German!

Comment: Maybe better delete the google-chrome tag if it is a problem with firefox (or even when it is not browser dependable)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `hl=en` at the end of the URL, after a `?` if there isn't already an `?`, after `&` otherwise.

Comment: [https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=mail&hl=en](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=mail&hl=en) - this link will open the Gmail login page in English. Gmail appears to ignore the `hl` tag once you're logged in - for that, [follow Google's instructions](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=69784) in setting the language for Gmail.

Comment: Actually, it varies depending from which part of Google one is using.  For Google Webmaster Tools, for example, the `hl` field is respected when one is logged in.

Answer (score 5):

**Gmail language:**

Under *Mail settings* → *General* → *Gmail display language* choose English.

**Google Chrome auto-translation:**

Disable `chrome://settings/advanced` → *Translate* → *Offer to translate pages...*

Comment: sry i do not mean chrome in particular. And its even before we login, the login page is already in German when i go http://gmail.com say with Firefox

Answer (score 4):

Use http://www.google.com/ncr to disable langage swap.
`NCR`=no country redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different method that worked for me, at top of email, click on "Turn off" in the translation box at the top of the message.  Very annoying to continually have to work around these new "features" of Google, perhaps there is a better web based mail?

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to `google preferences`

> https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en

then change `Region Settings` to `US` or whatever you like...