# How do I stop Google from translating its pages?

Tags: google, translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop Gmail from serving us auto translations based on our IP address?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16269/how-to-stop-gmail-from-serving-us-auto-translations-based-on-our-ip-address)

This is annoying me to no end.

**Edit:
Google is translating its pages and serving them translated. This not happening on client side (Chrome).**

I live in Czech Republic and everytime I visit a Google page like gmail.com, market.android.com etc. It shows up in Czech language.

Even worse, for some reason google.cz is default search in Chrome. I would really like google.com and no other.

Even though I speak Czech it bothers me. I wonder why this is?

I have English Windows, English Regional Setttings, English Chrome. I think it looks up geographic location and sees I'm in Czech Republic.

What about people who don't speak Czech? I imagine this must be a pain.

So the question is, how do I turn translating off?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `?hl=en` (or `&hl=en` if there are already parameters) to any Google URL to translate it. Other than that you need to change the setting for every service you use by clicking the gears in the top right corner (works only logged-in).

If you want to change this globally you can edit your `accept-language`-header in your browser but I'm not sure whether Google parses this (but i suppose so).

Comment: As far as I can tell, Google completely ignores the Accept-Language header sent by the browser. Which is very rude of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it by doing:

1. Select **Options** (**Preferences** on Mac and Linux; **Settings** on Chrome OS).
2. Click the **Under the Hood** tab.
3. Use the **"Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language I read"** checkbox to adjust this feature.

More options and how to use it can be found in [Google Chrome Help](https://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=173424&hl=en-US).

Comment: nope, this is not what I meant

Comment: @Kugel You said: _So the question is, how do I turn translating off?_ would you make your question a little bit more specific on what you want?

Comment: It is written clearly. It is google that translates pages and serves them in czech. Not Chrome browser on my side.

Answer (score 0):

To change Chrome's search engine to google.com:

1. Go to Options/Preferences -> Basics -> Search -> Manage Search Engines... [see here](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95653)
2. Add a new search engine and set it's URL like this `http://www.google.com/search?q=%s`
3. Make it default