# How to make Google's interface always be in your chosen language across products - not just search

Tags: google, localization, user-interface

I would like to reference and revisit the following post - [How do you make Google's interface always be in your chosen language?](https://superuser.com/questions/59118/how-do-you-make-googles-interface-always-be-in-your-chosen-language) - that has yet to be answered sufficiently.

Unfortunately none of the options proposed in that thread actually stick across Google products in the long term without constantly deleting cookies or re-install Chrome regularly.

I live in a foreign country and every possible language setting available in my Google account and products is set to English (Google settings/Chrome settings etc.), yet nonetheless I am almost always redirected to the product page that is in the local language.  There is no quick fix - and the issue isn't only with the search unfortunately, so the google.com/ncr is only an option when search is the product involved.  Also, setting the language to English using the cog wheel found on the search results page despite it saying "Which language should Google products use?" - it does not respect this setting.

When it comes to using alerts, Google Books, Google+, Play Store, and even Gmail sometimes - among others - despite having chosen English for use across Google products - the language preference is disregarded entirely.  There isn't even a quick link at the bottom of the page - like there once was to change the language setting.

Is there any other way besides via the Google settings themselves (that Google clearly disregards) - an app, a script, any other idea that will ensure that this does not recur?

Answer (score 3):

A quick fix would be to [add "&hl=en" to URL of the service you use](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16269/how-can-i-stop-gmail-from-serving-me-auto-translations-based-on-my-ip-address).

That, however, needs to be done manually for each session you start. 
I'm still [looking for an automation technique](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36403/any-way-to-auto-add-hl-en-to-urls-of-google-services) like a browser plugin for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try forwarding plugins for your browser. For example, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/redirect

The page I've linked to is the Chrome webstore and I did a search for redirect.

You may be able to find one in their which when it forwards you to the products page, it automatically redirects you to the language of your choice. Of course, you may have to know about querystrings etc and as I'm not a Chrome user I can't comment more (but I felt since you've had no luck else where it was better to suggest it than to not)