# Any way to auto-add "&hl=en" to URLs of Google services?

Tags: google, localization

Google tries to "help" users understand English language content in its various services like *Google Groups* when the reader is located in presumably non-English speaking territories.

There are [a few ways to prevent this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=google%20language), but they either involve using Google cookies, or manually modifying URL.

Does anyone know of some sort of a browser plugin which would add the required key to Google URLs automatically?

Comment: You could writa a Chrome extension or UserScript to do this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the browser scripting. Any nice & quick tutorial out there? I'm also using FF mostly.

Comment: I don't know of any. Basically all you need to do is making a manifest file for describing your extension and defining what websites it has to be included in and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

As your requirement is too specific, I don't think there will be any browser plugins for your scenario.

I would suggest that you write your own JavaScript bookmarklet (instead of a browser extension which is relatively harder IMO). The bookmarklet can be made to scan URLs within a document that pertain to Google Services of your interest and upon finding one, append “&hl=en”.

To get started with writing a bookmarklet, you can check my [Google Mobilizer bookmarklet](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2012/04/google-mobilizer-bookmarklet-view-just.html) which looks for links within Tweets and uses Google Mobilizer to show the text within the corresponding article links by modifying the original URL.